# union the table based on row value

Tags: sql-server

Below is my table structure.

```
declare @t1 table (id int identity,val int not null,datatype1  int null,datatype2  int null,datatype3  int null,datatype4  int null,type int)
declare @t2 table (id int identity,val int not null,datatype1  int null,datatype2  int null,datatype3  int null,datatype4  int null,type int)
insert into @t1 values (10,1,0,0,0,1),(31,1,0,0,0,1),(20,1,0,0,0,1),(30,1,0,0,0,1)
insert into @t2 values (31,0,1,0,0, 2),(4,0,0,1,0,3),(12,0,0,0,1,4),(31,0,0,0,1,4)

select * from @t1;
select * from @t2;
```

i am combining 2 table data with below query.

```
select val,max(datatype1) datatype1,max(datatype2)datatype2,max(datatype3)datatype3,max(datatype4)datatype4 from (
select * from @t1

union all

select * from @t2
 ) as data group by val
```

i need to change the logic if  val is 31 and type=2 in @t2 ,
 for these cases i need get 2 rows for val 31 and other cases  only distinct values

Expected Result:

```
val datatype1   datatype2   datatype3   datatype4
4    0             0            1        0
10   1             0            0        0
12   0             0            0        1
20   1             0            0        0
30   1             0            0        0
31   1             0            0        1
31   0             1            0        0       --- only if in @t2 val =31 and type=2
```

pls let me knwwat need to be changed for only value 31 and type=2

Comment: While you did include sample data, it is difficult to actually see what that data is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on provided data looks like `CASE` expression is the way to go:

```
select val,
  max(datatype1) datatype1,
  max(datatype2) datatype2,
  max(datatype3) datatype3,
  max(datatype4) datatype4 
from (
  select 't1' AS tab_name, * from @t1
  union all
  select 't2' AS tab_name, * from @t2
 ) as data 
group by val, CASE WHEN tab_name = 't2' and val=31 and type=2 THEN 1 END; 
              -- creating subgroup for this specific conditions
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24528e2423524aeaf3a43156839442fd)**

Comment: thanks ... i wil check ,,,but i need to group based on @t2 with val=31  and type= 2

Comment: @Ajt It is not a problem at all, just add a table name as discriminator to `UNION ALL` part

Comment: Thank a lot @Lukasz..you saved my day!..(congrats for  100k)

Comment: one more help...actually i have wrongly  mentioned val=31 , it was any number and type=2 remain the same... i have changed val=31 to count(*)>1 but no luck..pls suggest

Comment: @Ajt If it has to be any number from t2 then remove that condition `CASE WHEN tab_name = 't2' and type=2 THEN 1 END;`. If you want different logic  please consider asking new question.

Comment: i have raised quesion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520106/conditional-union-multiple-tables

Comment: pls let me is it possible? if it difficult pls provide me a logic...

Comment: @Ajt I see you extended a logic for 3 tables and 3 conditions. I guess it is possible to write such a query but it would not be a short query. Let's hope someone answers your new question with revised logic.