# conditional union multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is based on [union tables on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517117/union-the-table-based-on-row-value/59517134?noredirect=1#comment105234616_59517134)

```
declare @t1 table (val int,datatype1  int,datatype2  int ,datatype3  int)
declare @t2 table (val int,datatype1  int ,datatype2  int ,datatype3  int )
declare @t3 table (val int,datatype1  int ,datatype2  int ,datatype3  int )
insert into @t1 values (10,1,0,0),(31,1,0,0),(20,1,0,0)
insert into @t2 values (31,0,1,0),(4,0,1,0)
insert into @t3 values (31,0,0,1),(5,0,0,1);
```

Below is the changes in requirement(case):

```
1. need to union @t1,@t2 & @t3 
   (if same value exist @t1 & @t2 multiple rows and @t2 & t3 only 1 row)
2. if any duplicate value (there is no chance dup in same table)

 i) suppose 31 in @t1 , 31 in @t2 then multiple rows are allowed 
 ii) suppose 31 in  @t2 & @t3  then only one records i.e @t3 updated to @t2  
 iii) if 31 in @t1 ,@t2,@t3  only 2 records i.e @t1,@t2 records with @t3 details updated to @t2 records
```

Now i) & iii) are working fine

```
select val,
  max(datatype1) datatype1,
  max(datatype2)datatype2,
  max(datatype3)datatype3
from (
  select 't1' AS tab_name, * from @t1
  union all
  select 't2' AS tab_name,* from @t2
   union all
  select 't3' AS tab_name,* from @t3
 ) as data 
group by val,  CASE WHEN tab_name in ('t2')   THEN 1 END
order by val;
```

But  Current Result  showing multiple records for case 2 also any help

**Expected Result:**

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: It is really hard to follow what you want.  List the rules that you want *completely* in this question.   "Changes in requirements" are not helpful.  Including sample data *as tables* in the question also helps anyone reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to follow.  I'm a bit lost on the conditions, but this rather simple query returns the results that you specify:

```
select val,
       max(datatype1) as datatype1,
       max(datatype2) as datatype2,
       max(datatype3) as datatype3,
       max(datatype4) as datatype4 
from (select 't1' AS tab_name, t1.* from t1
      union all
      select 't2' AS tab_name, t2.* from t2
      union all
      select 't3' AS tab_name, t3.* from t3
     ) data 
group by val;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b79a6df6bc24e206978efd303e41f4c0) is a db<>fiddle.

I wonder if the culmination of all your results is a relatively simple aggregation.